# Where is the 'Expand All' feature in the search results tab in Eclipse Neon?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

In previous eclipse versions, when we search in projects, we had a 'Expand All' option in the search results (when we right click any project in the search results view). I can't find that in the latest Eclipse Neon version ? Is this feature removed or is it located somewhere else now ?

[image: Missing 'Expand All' option in search results tab]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Expand All is on the tool bar at the top right of the search results view:
[image: Search Toolbar]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Need to get rid of existing habits of right clicking and trying to expand all !!!